# R making a matrix of logical matrices

Tags: r

I've been trying to make a 1 row matrix that has logical matrices in each of the columns, but haven't been having very much luck.  I tried a for loop:

```
mat<-matrix(NULL,nrow=1,ncol=60)
for(i in 1:60){mat<-list(mat,matrix(FALSE,nrow=4,ncol=4))}
```

That produced a 4x4 matrix with weird sized submatrices.

```
mat<-matrix(NULL,n=row=1,ncol=60)
for(i in 1:60){mat[i]<-matrix(FALSE,nrow=4,ncol=4)}
```

That produced a NULLxNULL matrix with 60 FALSEs.

Comment: If all your matrices have the same size as in your example, I'd highly recommend you create a 3D `array`.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix in R is a strictly - defined array of elements.   You probably want a structure, or more simply, a `list` variable.

```
foo<- list() 
foo[1:4]<-1:4  #creates four elements in list variable. Short example; you'd use 1:60
foo[[1]]<- matrix(rep(TRUE,16),nr=4)
```

and so on.
But I am guessing you'd be a lot happier with a higher-dimension matrix instead of a structure like that.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is inherently 2 dimensional. You could make a data.frame where each column was a 4x4 matrix:

```
tmp <- data.frame(V1=logical(4))
for (i in 1:60) tmp[i] <- matrix(FALSE, nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

(This is an awkward way to make a data.frame because of the tendency of data.frames to spread out the columns of a matrix into different columns).

```
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  60 variables:
 $ V1 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V2 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V3 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V4 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V5 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V6 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V7 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V8 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V9 : logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V10: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V11: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V12: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V13: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V14: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V15: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V16: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V17: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V18: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V19: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V20: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V21: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V22: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V23: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V24: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V25: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V26: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V27: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V28: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V29: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V30: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V31: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V32: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V33: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V34: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V35: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V36: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V37: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V38: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V39: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V40: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V41: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V42: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V43: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V44: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V45: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V46: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V47: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V48: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V49: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V50: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V51: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V52: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V53: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V54: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V55: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V56: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V57: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V58: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V59: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ V60: logi [1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Alternatively, you can make a 3 dimensional array:

```
tmp <- array(FALSE, dim=c(60,4,4))
```

Indexing on the first dimension gives a 4x4 matrix:

```
> str(tmp)
 logi [1:60, 1:4, 1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
> tmp[1,,]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I think the latter is probably closer to what will be useful to you, but not knowing why you want that particular data structure, It's hard to say.

Building on [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039867/892313), you can make a list, each element of which is a 4x4 logical matrix:

```
tmp <- rep(list(matrix(FALSE, nrow=4, ncol=4)), 60)

> tmp[[1]]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And if you *really* want this to be a 1 by 60 structure, each element of which is a 4x4 logical matrix, then you can add dimensions to the list as well:

```
tmp <- rep(list(matrix(FALSE, nrow=4, ncol=4)), 60)
dim(tmp) <- c(1,60)
```

which can be accessed like:

```
> tmp[[1,3]]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> tmp
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,7]       [,8]       [,9]       [,10]      [,11]      [,12]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,13]      [,14]      [,15]      [,16]      [,17]      [,18]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,19]      [,20]      [,21]      [,22]      [,23]      [,24]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,25]      [,26]      [,27]      [,28]      [,29]      [,30]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,31]      [,32]      [,33]      [,34]      [,35]      [,36]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,37]      [,38]      [,39]      [,40]      [,41]      [,42]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,43]      [,44]      [,45]      [,46]      [,47]      [,48]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,49]      [,50]      [,51]      [,52]      [,53]      [,54]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
     [,55]      [,56]      [,57]      [,58]      [,59]      [,60]     
[1,] Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16 Logical,16
```

Not sure why you would want to do this, though.